# Inconveniente Conexión Php en Netbeans con Hosting Gratuito (FreeWHA)

Tags: php, mysql

Cordial saludo espero se encuentren bien, quiero pedirles el favor si me pueden indicar como conectar puedo una base de datos creada en phpmyadmin en la nube con el servidor freewha con un desarrollo sencillo que tengo en php, estoy usando el IDE NetBeans y el servidor Wamppserver . El código de conexión que tengo en php (abrir_conexion.php), es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost:3306";//Aquí es en donde estar el error el problema es que en el phpmyadmin en la nube tan solo me dice localhost, pero no me aparece ningún puerto, como se ve en la figura 1. 
$basededatos = "349049";
$usuariodb = "349049";
$clavedb = "mi contraseña";
error_reporting(0);
$conexion = new mysqli($host, $usuariodb, $clavedb, $basededatos);
echo  $conexion->connect_error;
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    error_log("Sitio experimenta fallos: nº: $conexion->connect_errno, Error: $conexion->connect_error " . $mysqli->connect_errno);
   throw new ErrorException("Error de conexion a mysql: nº: $conexion->connect_errno, Error: $conexion->connect_error");
   exit();
    echo "Error en conexion  "; 
}else{
    echo "Conexion exitosa ";
   }
$conexion->set_charset("utf8");
?>
```

Al ejecutar el archivo de conexión me muestra el siguiente error: Acceso denegado para el usuario '349049'@'localhost' (con contraseña: SÍ), He buscado ver como arreglar este inconveniente, pero no me ha sido posible. ¡Muchas gracias por su colaboración!

Att. Hernán Martínez

Comment: Entiendo que eso te lo deben resolver en el hosting ese. He mirado su FAQ y dicen que primero debes hacer es ir a tu cuenta y crear una base de datos, y alli poner un usuario y contraseña **para la base de datos** (no son el mismo usuario y contraseña de tu cuenta, ojo con eso).  Ves alli y mira lo que pusistes o borra lo que haya y empieza de nuevo apuntandote esos datos y poniendolos en tu script.

Comment: Hola Masterguru muchas gracias, estaré murando como conectar  la aplicación en Php con la base de datos.